# If the argument name was removed at compiled time, how the Spring LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer get the name by reading class file?

Tags: java, spring

For the same Junbin.java file, The outputs compiled by javac, javac -parameters and gradle build are different.
I would like to state problem that confused me with three case.

the original file Junbin.java

```
public class Junbin {
    public Junbin() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] ko) throws UnknownHostException, SocketException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("-----");
    }

    public static void t(List<? super Integer> lis) {
        lis.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
    }
}
```

1, javac Junbin.Java -parameters
In the first case, The arguments "ko" of main method can be got by Method.getParameters() added in Java8.

2, javac Junbin.java
If I don't add -parameter option on javac, Method.getParameters()[0].getName() printed arg0, not "ko".

For the two cases above, The compiled class file viewed in Intellij idea shows below.

```
public class Junbin {
    public Junbin() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] var0) throws UnknownHostException, SocketException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("-----");
    }

    public static void t(List<? super Integer> var0) {
        var0.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
    }
}
```

The arguments name are all arg0.

3, gradle build
Method.getParameters cannot get the "ko".
But, The output class compiled by gradle opened in Intellij idea is right.
as shown below

```
public class Junbin {
    public Junbin() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] ko) throws UnknownHostException, SocketException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("-----");
    }

    public static void t(List<? super Integer> lis) {
        lis.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
    }
}
```

I can definitely get the argument name "ko" by Spring's LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.

If the argument name was removed at compiled time, how the Spring LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer get the arguments name by read class file?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not blurry images.

Comment: OK, now all the codes are shown as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses debug info map as stated in the following source code snapshot:

```
Map<Member, String[]> map = this.parameterNamesCache.get(declaringClass);
if (map == null) {
    map = inspectClass(declaringClass);
    this.parameterNamesCache.put(declaringClass, map);
}
if (map != NO_DEBUG_INFO_MAP) {
    return map.get(originalMethod);
}
```

So when you compile you source file debug symbols get saved. If you compile the file without them it won't show you any method names as well. So, obviously, Intellij Idea doesn't use debug symbols at all, that's all the explanation:)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I understood it by using -g option to compile java file